# RequestStack not transmitted by autowire in service - symfony 3.3.9

Tags: symfony, service, request, autowired, symfony-3.3

I created a service that needs access to the user's request, so I use the RequestStack in my service constructor but even if autowire's true, I don't receive the RequestStack object, I have null instead.

Here's the code of the service :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service\System;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class User
{
    protected $requestStack;

    public function __contruct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        $request=$this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the code of the controller calling the service by the new DI :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use AppBundle\Service\System\User;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(User $user)
    {
        $u=$user->getUser();
    }
}
```

It ends in an error for calling getCurrentRequest() on null.

Is there something special for the RequestStack to be autowired ? Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you are using $user = new User() instead of injecting user.

Comment: No, User is injected in another service called Connexion, and I don't instantiate User, neither Connexion.

Comment: Hmmm.  If you are in development mode then you would get an error about a missing constructor argument.  Something else is going on.  Does bin/console debug:container --show-private show the service?  Does your posted code really reflect your actual code or did you "clean" it up.

Comment: Yes, the debug;container shows the "request_stack" service. The posted code is the actual code, I cleaned it up to test with the minimum so that I could exclude anything else.
I even tested my User service in a simple controller with public function indexAction(User $user) { $u=$user->getUser(); } but it doesn't work either. I tested withanother service of mine which does not receive RequestStack and it works well

Comment: Notice anything unusual about __contruct() ?

Comment: No, nothing more than in the code up there.

Comment: Maybe the spelling?

Comment: I edited my post to copy/paste the exact code of my test, with the service and a controller using it. I have checked several times but I see no typo

Comment: Might be time to take a break.  You really don't see the difference between __contruct and __construct ?  Having a misspelled constructor function explains all the symptoms.

Comment: Well... You're right, it's time to sleep... Thanks a lot for your perseverance and patience, and sorry for such a mistake...